# Advantage of using visual studio on windows for iphone app development over native environment

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I am reading a way to setup iphone application development environment on my windows. It [states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/index) that “A network-accessible Mac set up with Apple's build tool” is required. My confusion is that, if i need to buy a mac machine and need to setup an envionment then why i will use windows and visual studio?

I am exploring why it is advantageous for me to build ios app in xamarin when i need to buy mac machine and install xcode. Why i will use xamarin when i am new to both C# and swift?
Please ignore my limited knowledge and flaw in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Xamarin to build apps

- enables C# developers (there are millions of them) to leverage the language and framework they already know instead of learning a completely new one
- allows them to share code between existing C# apps written for the web or desktop (very important in an Enterprise environment)
- using Xamarin Forms, allows you to create a single codebase that targets multiple platforms (iOS, Android, UWP, etc)

if all you care about is iOS and you don't already know C#, then Xamarin may be of limited benefit to you